# partnerships problems

Tags: logic

Naveed and Faraz start a business by investing Rs 3000 and Rs 5000 respectively.Four months later, Naveed invests an extra Rs 2000 and Faraz invests an extra Rs 3000. At the end of the year, what should be the ratio in which they distribute the profits of the business?

Answer (score 1):

Naveed has invested $3000$ for $12$ months and $2000$ for $12-4=8$ months

So, his effective investement $=12\cdot3000+8\cdot2000$

Similarly, for Faraz

The ratio should of their respective investments unless otherwise spcified

Comment: cant understand

Comment: @AmnaFayyaz, If Navved, Faraz  invest $x,y$ respectively; the profit/loss should be distributed in the same ratio i.e, $x:y$

Comment: the answer is 18:25 how?